# Вопрос про ссылочный тип

Tags: java

```
class test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Integer b,a;

        a = 4;

        b = a;

        a = 334;

        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Почему в данном случае b не изменил значение ? разве это не ссылочный тип, как объект класса.

Comment: Потому что вы меняете саму ссылку, содержащуюся в переменной, а не значение по ссылке.

Comment: выше приведенный код,вероятно, эквивалентен   
    a = new Integer(4);
   b = a;
   a = new Integer(334);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменные объектных (или ссылочных) типов хранят ссылки на сами объекты.

В строке `a = 4;` создается* объект класса `Integer` и ссылка на этот объект помещается в переменную `a`.

В строке `b = a` ссылка, хранящаяся в переменной `a` копируется в переменную `b`. После этого переменные `a` и `b` ссылаются на один и тот же объект.

Далее, в строке `a = 334;` создается объект класса `Integer` и ссылка на него помещается в переменную `a`. Здесь не происходит никаких манипуляций с переменной `b`.

*в случае, если объект с таким же значением был создан ранее и он хранится в пуле, то новый объект создаваться не будет, вместо этого будет использован объект из пула.